# PC restarts as soon as a game is opened

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, reboot, desktop-computer

My computer restarts (power dies completely and the PC is effectively off for 1 second before it switches on again by itself) under 2 conditions:

1) At random after running under low work load for 6+ hours. By low work load I mean browsing the web, playing music/videos and running various software packages.

2) Almost immediately after starting up any computer game. In all cases these are games that had previously run on the same computer smoothly and without any problem for multiple hours.

I've checked Windows 10 Event Viewer which lists the following:
**Event Type:** Critical
**Event ID**: 41
**Source:** Kernel Power
**Log:** System

This leads me to believe that the Power Supply Unit is toast and needs to be replaced. Is this a safe assumption or is there anything else I should check before buying a new PSU?

Thanks
Willem

Comment: Beside PSU I would check what frequency and multiplier are set for CPU and RAM in BIOS. Maybe they've changed and are the problem.

Comment: Apart from the PSU, you can also look into the thermals of your PC. If the CPU/GPU get hot, they will thermal throttle, reducing the maximun load they can get to, and, in some cases, they will cause the computer to shut off. You can use programs like GPU-Z to see the temps. If this happens to be the case you can head to the Advanced power configuration of your power plan, and limit the maximun load of your CPU, to limit the temperature, or disable Intel Turbo Boost within your BIOS, if your CPU supports it, as a temporary solution. BTW, the event means that an unexpected shut off occurred.